# protected DataSet against SQL Inejection

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset, sql-injection

I want to create a class that I can get datatable of specific table given in the parameter of the constructor.

But how I can do it without it being vulnerable to SQL Injections?

I would've done something like this: (But you can't use those statements like that)

```
public class SqlClass
{

    DataTable dt;

    string table;

    public SqlClass(String table)
    {
        this.table = table;
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
        c.conOpen();
        MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @tableName", c.Con); //Cant do that
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", table);
        DataSet ds = c.getDataSet(msc, table);
        this.dt = ds.Tables[table];
        c.conClose();
    }

    public DataTable Dt { get => dt; set { dt = value; } }

}
```

Any other working alternative that won't harm me? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you don't really want to do that. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MitchWheat I want to find a protected way to get all table data, by table name given as a parameter,

Comment: you can check if the input is a valid table name by comparing it with the output of `SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: I don' t see any use of this. it only makes sense if user of the appl can type the name of the table in the input field. But I 've never met this kind of appl.

Comment: @Sergey So just to make it clear, if the data is not from a user input, its 100% safe from SQL injections? Even without prepare statements? As I'm not sure if they can find a bypass or something.

Comment: When user has a possiblily to type some extra code in the input field  it is called an Sql injection. This is why you have always validate an user input on the server side before to send to database.  But  since your query is on the server side there is no way that user can inject something extra. Or to say more precisely if somebody will find the  way to change your query string , he will never use the parameters. So parameters wil be useless in this case.

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: As per above? Don't see problem with building the sql string in code that includes the concatenation of the table name. Since as others noted, that table name choice never comes from the user, then it should not be a problem. it is VERY doubtful that the user is typing in the table name for this to work. In fact, you can setup the sqlCMD object, and even add/change the string used - and that can even include concatenation of additonal where clause parameters in that string. Since that is not user input, then you are free to add 1 or 5 parameter's as concatenated strings into the where clause.